# ASP net core - Change the data before display in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to ASP.net Core 3.1 and i'm searching since 3 days how to change the data retrieved from the database before displaying it...
Let me explain it to you more clearly :

I have a table in the database where i have multiples column : id, name, coordinate_x...
So to display the entries of my table i use following code in my Controller :

```
var myTable= _context.MyTable.Include(a => a.ItsParentTable);
return View(await MyTable.ToListAsync());
```

And then in the view i display it with a foreach :

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Coordinate_X)</td>
}
```

the thing is that before displaying it, **i want to add 500 into the value of my coordinate_x (without changing the value in the database..)**

Do you have any clues how i can do it please ?

Comment: `@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Coordinate_X + 500)`?

Comment: You want EVERY `Coordinate_X` to have 500 added to it?  Then something like @HereticMonkey suggested should work.  If you want just one record to be different, you would probably have to tweak `myTable` in the controller, or extract the data from `myTable`, tweak it, and then pass it to the `View` constructor.

Comment: i got an exception when i try this..
InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Comment: I use IEnumerable as model reference to list my table..